# Using Built In SQL File in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, database-connection, sql-server-2012

I am creating a windows application using Visual Studio 2012 and using its built in SQL Server,
I have created the database and tables but unable to access the database.
I am trying to insert values in tables using insert query but it is showing error Ünable to connect to server

The connection string that I am using is

```
    <connectionStrings>
        <add     name="GRTU_Library_Management.Properties.Settings.GRTU_Library_ManagementConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|    \GRTU_Library_Management.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

and the query that I am trying is

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("GRTU_Library_Management.Properties.Settings.GRTU_Library_ManagementConnectionString");

        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Category values('" + txtcategory.Text + "')", con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
```

please help me in this regard,

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no constructor of the [`SqlConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx) class that accepts the *name* of a connection string.

If you want to retrieve a connection string from a config file, you have to do it yourself, maybe via the [`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings.aspx).

```cs
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["GRTU_Library_Management.Properties.Settings.GRTU_Library_ManagementConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, I added the configuration in references and it starts working.